# Turning comma seperated stdin line to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Have the following code:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
        dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES ('noline')")
        dbcon.commit()
try:
    dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES ('dict')")
    dbcon.commit()
    mydict = dict(line.split(','))

    dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES ('" + mydict.tostr() + "')")
    dbcon.commit()
    dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES ('here')")
    dbcon.commit()

except Exception, e:
    sys.stderr.write(str(e))
```

In my database (the sql entries are just to test where stdin gets to, since I can't run from command line and test)--I get to "dict", so I'm guessing my way of doing what I'm asking to do is not correct.

Comment: line.split() makes a list, not a dict.  do you need it to be a dict?

Comment: yea.  super newb to python.  With how short programs are, figured methods like that worked on anything.  But now that makes sense :D

Comment: so does that mean that changing to a list is the solution?

Comment: I'm wanting to take essentially a csv log, and put certain fields in a database.  When I googled--dictionary was first thing that came up, and to me that makes sense.  But on second thought, only the initial header giving column names makes sense--as any line afterwards is variable.  so maybe I do need a list?

Comment: doing: list = list(line.split(',')), I still never end up to 'here'...changing to list[], will update. UPDATE list = list[line.split(,)] also doesnt work.

Comment: you just need `list = line.split(',')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52483/discussion-between-honi-and-brizz)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate over the list and do an `INSERT` one by one.

Also, to help mitigate the potential for SQL injection, you shouldn't directly interpolate the values into the `INSERT`, but, rather, use the `%s` syntax and add a list of bindings to the `execute` call.

Alternatively, you can leverage the `%s` syntax to `INSERT` a bunch of values at once. i.e. determine the length of your list and calculate the string of `%s`, i.e. something like:

```
thelist = line.split(',')
bindingStrList = len(thelist) * '%s'
dbcur.execute("INSERT INTO test(event_type) VALUES ({0})".format(', '.join(bindingStrList)), thelist)
```

**Note:** My code above assumes `psycopg2`, but the concept in general should apply even to other libraries to interface with postgres.